# Unspecified number of variables within a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm writing a simple program using structures. The structure I have a problem with is supposed be flexible when it comes to the number of variables within the definition of a said structure. The program is to download the number from a file with .txt extension:

```
ints: 5
strings: 6
```

then create a defined number of ints and strings in the structure. At first I was thinking about using pointers within the struct:

```
struct Data
{
      int* intArr;
      string* stringArr;
};
```

But after a quick search it turned out to be an ineffective way to go about the problem. The biggest challenge is... that I cannot use STL. 
Could you please point me in the right direction?
Hardly am I an experienced programmer so I apologise if the question is inaccurate or just plainly wrong.

Comment: Why would your solution be ineffective?

Comment: It is ineffective if you define a fixed amount of ints, but you can use a pointer to dynamic memory which grows with the amount of variables

Comment: Most answers stated that in C++ it is compulsory to do as much as possible during the process of compiling, not during the run-time of a program

Comment: @Jose That's great to hear! Thank you! Is there any way to use void* instead of actually typing all possible data types? I would like the program to be able to work on multiple data types with different config files (of course still maintaining said structure of a file)

Comment: When you say "all possible data types", I start thinking that you've almost certainly misunderstood the exercise.

Comment: Okay, this was inaccurate statement. I meant the basic data types like ints, doubles, floats, strings, chars, etc

Comment: You could store them as `void*`, but to use them you'd have to cast them back, which means you'd have to know what type they are, which means you'd need to to the type for each value, so you might as well just store them as the right type.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understood your problem correctly but what you have mentioned it seems you want to bind variable number of information to a structure.

Use double pointer as variable in the structure to allocate address of array or pointers. This should solve your problem of variable number of members.

```
    struct X
    {
    int **ptr;
    };

    X a;
    a.ptr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);
```

This should create 10 pointers and allocate address of created pointer to structure member variable. This value 10 can vary at run time.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, what is the difference between a.ptr=malloc (sizeof(int*)*10); and a.ptr = new int *[10];?

Comment: @ReeD my apologies for late reply. To answer your question, the way in which new and malloc allocates memory is different that's why we should not use delete with malloc and free with new. But I dont think this make a big difference in your problem. Suggest you to read these articles. 
https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-new-and-malloc.html
https://www.javatpoint.com/malloc-vs-new-in-cpp

Answer (score 0):

`void*` is convertible to any data type, you can do `void *var = new char` and  is valid, but `void` has not size, so it is useless to allocate different types together, because you'll have to know the type in order to dereference the pointer (and/or the length to iterate over it), but you don't know it, unless you track all the types, but as you can suppose, this is really ineffective.

If you want to allocate memory for different datatypes, do it in the right way, that is, a pointer for each type:

```
int * foo;
foo = new int[N];
```

```
char * bar;
bar = new bar[N];
```

---

Regarding the ineffectiveness, bear in mind that you have two ways, calculate the worst case scenario and reserve the memory at compilation time (i.e. `char charArray[50]; int intArray[200]`), or use new/delete to allocate memory based on the runtime requirements (which is what stl is going to do under the hood, unless you use `std::array`)

Comment: After some thought this seems to be the best course of action. Again, thank you so much for you help! Have a good one